# Why does rsync not create a hard link in my Backup Set?

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

I am trying to set up an rsync Backup from my Windows pc to my raspi. On the raspi I have an NTFS formatted usb stick.
When I sync files to the target everything works fine, except that rsync will not create any hardlinks.
My rsync looks like this:

```
rsync -avvvvhP --modify-window=5 --delete --link-dest=/mnt/usbstick1/1/ -e 'ssh -p 22' /cygdrive/d/priv/file1.png root@192.168.1.125:/mnt/usbstick1/2/
```

The testfile file1.png has already been synced to folder 1.

I check the inode on the filesystem using ll -i.

I also tried to log in to the remote system and performed a local sync: This works as expected.
Only when I try this from remote from Windows it always fails. I tried modify-window, -c (checksum), -H no matter what I just can't get this feature to work from windows.
On windows I use GnuWin32 and CWRsync5.5.0

```
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
 64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 32-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
append, ACLs, no xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc).
```

Any ideas what the problem could be ?

Stefan

Comment: Have you tried testing the command locally on a plain ext4 filesystem? I"m not sure of the state of the Linux ntfs driver with hardlinks. Also I know rsync is really picky about traililng slashes in general and it's easy to mess up with the --link-dest argument. Testing the sync between two ext3/4 filesystems would eliminate those variables at least.

Comment: I tried this already, a local sync on the ntfs file system works as expected! I also tried different combinations of trailing slashes to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `-H` option: from [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links

This option is **not** included in `-a`:

> **-a**
>
> This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a notable omission).

Comment: I tried -H but it does not work. According to varies sources -H will try to preserve hard links existing in the source data, not create hard links on the destination if the file already exists. This what --link-dest is supposed to do in my opinion.